# Chrome console search through all JS files for a string of text?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I've come across lots of SO posts all telling me to use: cmd+option+f to do this.

I open the console and press: command + option + f. and am taken to sources tab. There's a search box. It searches through the current file that I have selected on the left. Is there a way to search through all JS files with one search?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, press `Esc` and use the `Search` tab:

[image: Chrome search tab]

Comment: There's a shortcut, `Ctrl-Shift-F`